# How to copy Skype text with timestamp and names in MacOS

Tags: macos, skype, clipboard, timestamp

When I select and copy some text from Skype chat, it does not include timestamp and name if I take only one message from one user. If it is two or more messages, timestamps and names are there.

For example, if there is a chat like this:

---

User1:

Hi, how are you? [10:00]

User2:

I'm fine. [10:01]

---

I want to have in my clipboard something like '[User2 10:01] I'm fine'. But what I get is just 'I'm fine'. The only workaround I found is to include some part of previous message, but this is not what I really want. It is also not possible to select just a name and/or timestamp, you can select only a text, Skype adds names a timestamps automatically if you select more than 1 message.

Everything worked fine in Windows and Linux, is there any chance to get it working in MacOS without workarounds?